# eliminate maven dependency duplication

Tags: maven-2, dependency-management

In my Maven build, I use the antrun plugin to invoke an ant task.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                            <java classname="org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher"
                                fork="true" failonerror="true">
                                <classpath>
                                    <pathelement path="${plugin_classpath}" />
                                </classpath>
                            </java>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <dependencies>
                <!-- DEPENDENCIES FROM PROJECT DUPLICATED HERE -->
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I need to duplicate all the project dependencies in the section indicated, so that they are available to the ant task. Is there a way to avoid this duplication, by referring to the project's dependencies instead of copy-pasting them?

Comment: I think you can make it depend on the artefact you're building, and all the dependencies are added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

```
<property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />
<property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
<java classname="org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher"
      fork="true" failonerror="true">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${plugin_classpath}" />
        <pathelement path="${compile_classpath}" />
    </classpath>
</java>
```

**Reference:**

- [Maven Antrun Plugin > Referencing the Maven Classpaths](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html)